# Modification For AJAX Instant Search

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I have build an instant search with AJAX using [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) tutorial, I am getting instant result but the problem is the div in which result comes stays open there.

I want to modify it like after getting instant result, then

1. when clicked anywhere on page the result(div) should disappear.
2. and when mouse-over again on input field result(div) should reappear.

AJAX Code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("search-result").style.border="0px";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","instant-search.php?keyword="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
    <div id="search">
<form action="" method="get" id="search-form" >

<input name="" type="" size="" id="search-input" onkeydown="showResult(this.value)"/>

<select name="" id="search-select">
<option value="all" >All</option>
<input type="hidden" name="" value="" />
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Search" id="search-btn" /> 

</form>      
</div>
<div id="search-result"></div>
```

PHP Codes are simple MySQL Full Text Search query.

I tried like adding this but nothing happens

```
        <input name="keyword" type="text" size="50" id="search-input" onkeydown="showResult(this.value)" onclick="(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';"  onmouseout="showResult(this.value='';)"/>
```

Please suggest any way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to mention but its much easier in jQuery using the success callback.

Comment: Ya but I don't want to use jquery. any solution you know for this.

Comment: I'm afraid i only have a jQuery answer for you

Comment: @TallboY I'm agree with sam, with Jquery is rlly easy, practical, you will have less code

Answer (score 0):

A nasty way

```
<body>
<div id="main" onclick="fx(0)">

<div id="search">
<form action="" method="get" id="search-form" >
<input name="" type="" size="" id="search-input" onkeydown="showResult(this.value)"/>
<select name="" id="search-select">
<option value="all" >All</option>
<input type="hidden" name="" value="" />
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="search-btn" /> 
</form>      
</div>
<div id="search-result" onclick="fx(1)"></div>

</div>
</body>

<script>
function fx(var flag)
{
  // document.getElementById(theIdYouWantToShowHide).style.display="none" or inline or block ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: that's the question how to hide in java-script, in jquery i can use show(), hide()

Comment: thanks anyways, i got it though the same way. appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally, hope this helps others too.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("search-result").style.border="0px";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseover = function(){show_box()};
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","instant-search.php?keyword="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function close_box(){
document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="none";
}
 function show_box(){
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
}

document.onclick = function(){close_box()};

</script>
```